# Firebase Firestore FCM message sending issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

**My code :**

```
exports.fcmSend = functions.firestore.document('messages/{userId}').onCreate(event => {
    console.log("fcm send method");
    const message = event.data.data();
    const userId = event.params.userId;
    const token_id = 'asdfsadfdsafds';
    let token = "";
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Test",
            body: "Test",
            icon: "https://placeimg.com/250/250/people"
        }
    };
    db.collection('fcmTokens').doc('token_id').get().then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        const data = doc.data();
        token = data.token;
        console.log("token", token);
    })
    .then(() => {
        return event.data.ref.set({"title": "hello"}).sendToDevice(token, payload);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        return err;
    });
});
```

**Error :**

> Error getting documents TypeError:
>   event.data.ref.set(...).sendToDevice is not a function
>       at db.collection.doc.get.then.then (/user_code/index.js:117:50)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate Firebase products involved here:

1. Cloud Firestore, where you stroke the FCM tokens for a user.
2. the [Cloud Messaging Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin), which you use to [send notifications to a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices).

The `sendToDevice` method  exists on the Admin SDK for Cloud Messaging, not on a Firestore database reference where you're trying to invoke it.

To fix the problem you'll first need to import the Admin SDK into your `index.js`:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Then you modify your functions for step 1 and 2. It should look something like this:

```
// Load the tokens from Firestore
db.collection('fcmTokens').doc('token_id').get().then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    const data = doc.data();
    token = data.token;
    console.log("token", token);

    const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: 'hello',
          }
        };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    return err;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replay and i got the issue